# How to maintain separate permalink structure for specific category posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi Currently in our wordpress our default permalink structure is

`abc.com/%postname%-%post_id%.html`

But for specific category I want different permalink structure
Ex: for Photos Category i want url structure as

`abc.com/%post_id%.html`

Current i am using the following code But it is not working

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "Photos" ) {
        $permalink = home_url('/'.$post->ID .'.html' );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

But i am not getting different permalink structure for specific category posts. Please help me.

Comment: Whenever you attempt to alter permalink settings, you also need to `Flush Rewrite Rules` to have them updated (you can check the database to verify this). The code you've written has never taken affect if you've not done `flush_rewite_rules()` or gone to the `permalink` page in the backend and clicked on `Save` to refresh the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Posts must have a non-numeric slug because slug is an unique identifier.

So please use %post_id% in conjunction with other text. That will surely work.

The custom permalink url like abc.com/%post_id%.html for specific category post is not possible and the same topic is discussed on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/post_id-only-permalink-comes-with-date-and-death-links.